# How to add foregin key to aspnetroles table in EF Core code first approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I created a sample application in ASP.NET Core with authentication.
Few tables have been created and app works well.

Now I need to create new table "Organizations". This table should be connected with default table "AspNetRoles" by foregin key in relation one to many.
Each role may has many organizations associated.
The problem is, I cant find these default table in my application and do not know how to create a foreign key using code first approach.
I tried something like this:

```
public class Organization
{
   public int OrganizationId {get; set;}

   [ForeginKey="AspNetRoles"]
   public int RoleId {get; set;}

}
```

Help.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I find out how to achieve that.

```
public virtual string RoleId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("RoleId")]
public virtual IdentityRole Roles { get;set; }
```

AspNetRoles is called IdentityRole.

Comment: HI @justme there will be a one to many relationship from IdentityRole table to the table containing IdentityRoles as foreign table, Can u please tell how did u achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a navigation property to the related entity simply name the relevant key same as the navigation property followed by Id or ID and the EF will automatically recognize it as a foreign key for the related entity (e.g. Role - RoleId).

```
public string RoleId { get; set; }
public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
```

you can read more about [naming conventions in EF Code First here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in)

additionally here is a nice [tutorial on complex data models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)